# Padding/Margin for Images within a DIV

Tags: css, image, padding, margin

Ok.  I recently made some updates to this website.

http://annberingerart.com/index.php

Upon making some minor changes it seems that the margin and padding for the images on the index page has changed.  I would like for there to be equal padding both vertically and horizontally between all images as well as a consistent margin.

In addition, I was viewing the website on a friend's MAC with Safari 5 installed and the entire wrapper seemed to have shrunk in size because it could not contain its children as it had before I made the changes.

You can take a look at the CSS in firebug as it would be lengthy and excessive to post 400+ lines of CSS on here.

Any and all criticism is welcome, but I mostly want advice on how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your horizontal margin is caused by spaces / new-lines because the images are inline elements (sort of inline-block really...).

If you float the images, you will have more control over the exact margins instead of depending on the width of a space / new-line.

To solve your problem, you could:

- float the images left;
- give the wrapper a left-padding, no right-padding and an `overflow:hidden`;
- give all images a right padding (the same as the left-padding of the wrapper).

Comment: +1 for float, but just make sure the images are all the same height and/or each row has `clear:left` or the floats will drop.

Comment: @Ross, the images all seem to have the same dimension so that shouldn´t be a problem; everything will flow automatically, even if they decide to go to for example more or less columns in the future. All as long as the widths and paddings add up to the width of the wrapper...

Comment: I will implement this idea on the test site and see if it works.  Also, are you aware of any problems with Safari 5 on MAC OSX?  I was viewing the site and it looked like it shrunk the wrapper by at least 10px and moved all images into 2 columns...

Comment: @Dan, I have had problems in the past with webkit when I didn´t set a specific width for the wrapper, but I don´t know if that´s still a problem. By the way, don´t forget to give your wrapper a `overflow:hidden` so that it wraps the images (otherwise the height will not wrap).